# Defining types in Node.JS using Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

When I use Visual Studio Code to program node.js, I get some simple, yet pretty useful code completion recommendations. For example, if there is a callback, it tells me the signature and what type are the parameters.

I'd like to have this in self-written code too. What can I do so that VS Code can give meaningful code-completion suggestions?

E.g. using express, a third-party library I get

[image]

But in a method created I get the following, not so helpful popup.

[image]
    exports.getLastPrice = (market, callback) => {
        ...
        callback(result1, result2)
    }

What must I do so that I can get good suggestions about my own code? 
Thanks!

EDIT: Improved the question with screenshots

Comment: visual studio code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the error

Comment: @Daniel, check out [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't think there's an error ...

Comment: There is no error, its just that VS code doesn't give me any help and given that it gives recommendations for third party code, I'd like to know what must I do so that it also offers the same for my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code will use Javascript docstrings if you provide them. For example this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} param1 
 * @param {function(number, string):string} callback 
 */
function method1(param1, callback) {
    callback(result1, result2)
}
```

…gives me code completion help like this:

[image]

Docstring is well documented here: http://usejsdoc.org.
Is that what you're after?

Comment: by the way, how do you tag people on StackOverflow? it never works me haha